# Jquery Ajax result weird behavior. Need suggestions

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have an ajax call to my WCF service that records all click into a server. My jquery code that communicates with my service is below

```
function recordClick(message)
{

     var a =  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://10.4.201.39:8011/MyService.svc/AddTimeStampToFile" ,
            data: {videoName: message},
            dataType: "json",
            success: serviceSuccess,
            error: errorMessage
     });
     alert(a); ????? // If I delete this line My service always return Error

 }

 function serviceSuccess(data) {
     alert("Click Recorded");  
 }
 function errorMessage () {
     alert("Click Recording Error");
 }
```

Now I am not sure if I am missing something or there are many programmers out there that has similar experience, when I remove the line

```
alert (a);
```

in my recordClick function it always throw error. This tells me thatI will have something to do to the result which on this case I dont want to do any.

If this may help: My AddTimeStamp WCF Service returns an int which I used mainly for testing purposes.

Comment: $('#linkName').click(); this is useless ?

Comment: Yes Nikola. I updated my question, thanks for the observation.

Comment: If You are using Google Chrome, please add output of console (press F12 and open Console tab)

Comment: To clarify, with `alert(a);` in place you get a second alert with `Click Recorded` as the message and without `alert(a);` you get a single alert with `Click Recording Error` as the message? Is that correct?

Comment: The code above works well and the event goes like alert(Click Recorded) is fired then alert(a) is fired. When the line alert(a) is then deleted- the ajax call somehow is doing a weird behavior that it always fires the alert("Click Recording Error") - this thing to me is really weird. The whole code is working just the fact that I wanted to know why its doing such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your click event incorrectly, use this instead:

```
$('#linkName').click(function() {
  var a =  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://10.4.201.39:8011/MyService.svc/AddTimeStampToFile" ,
         data: {videoName: message},
         dataType: "json",
         success: serviceSuccess,
         error: errorMessage
  });
  alert(a); ????? // If I delete this line My service always return Error

 });

function serviceSuccess(data) {
  alert("Click Recorded");    
 }  

 function errorMessage () {
  alert("Click Recording Error");  
 }
```

Comment: `$('#linkName').click();` merely fires the event handler, which may be what the OP wants. It certainly is not the cause of the error.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question as per linkName.Click. This actually fires an event that downloads a file- this has nothing to do with my ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `recordClick` function to this:

```
function recordClick(message) {
    $('#linkName').click(); //fire the click event handler for #linkName
    $.ajax({
        "type": "GET",
        "url": "http://10.4.201.39:8011/MyService.svc/AddTimeStampToFile" ,
        "data": {
            "videoName": message
        },
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
        },
        "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ':' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I tried this and did not work on my side. My call to service works smooth when I did something with "var a" which on this case i use alert. WHen I remove this line it completely do something else that I am not certain of but the end result is that my service call is not successful.

Comment: Update: I run your code and error was thrown with textStatus= "error" and errorThrown has no value.

Comment: @jepoyscreepers: Found a typo in my answer which may have caused the error. Please try the code in the updated answer and post your results.